# How to define a private variable in a PHP class and use it in its methods

Tags: php, mysql, class

I have written a class in PHP in order to access to Mysql and doing some operations on it. But, I do not know how to define a private variable for database connection so that I do not need to define it in each of my methods Now, I define the connection in each method and know this is not a correct way. Please have a look at my code and tell me how to optimize it. Please pay attention to the construct method.

```
class SimpleClass
{

var $data = array();
var $db=0;

 function SimpleClass(){

   $this->$db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
   $this->$db->connect();
 }

public function test()
{

   $db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
   $db->connect();

   $q="SELECT * FROM `tbl_test`;";
   $rows = $db->query($q);

            while ($record = $db->fetch_array($rows)) {
          //...........codes
                }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are nearly there. You only have to take care not to confuse `$this->db` (the object property you want) and `$db` (some variable in the local scope of an object method, not helpful here).

Comment: Apart from that: you appear to be following a _really_ outdated tutorial... in php class cunstructor methods are named `__construct()`, the class name has not been used any more for ages...

Comment: Also note that it should be `$this->db`, not `$this->$db`...

Comment: You are reading a really really old tutorial (PHP4).

Comment: Before you go down this road, **especially** if you're using out-of-date material, look at modern ORMs like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent). They may already do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SimpleClass
{

    private $db;

    function SimpleClass(){

        $this->db = new Database(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
        $this->db->connect();
    }

    public function test()
    {


        $q="SELECT * FROM `tbl_test`;";
        $rows = $this->db->query($q);

        while ($record = $this->db->fetch_array($rows)) {
            //...........codes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private $data = array();
    private $db=0;
```

And accessing those fields is like this:

```
    $this->db = 5;
```

Note the missing $ in front of db!

And for all other member functions, prefix your variables with $this-> and remove the $ sign for the variables!

You should also call the member functions using the same $this->FUNCTION_NAME pattern.